# How does one correctly configures Android Context in UnitTests with Mockito 2.6.1 to avoid UnnecessaryStubbingException?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a unit test which internally is using  mocked Context to return certain strings, and this the logic I want to verify.

After updating to Mockito 2.6.1, I started getting `UnnecessaryStubbingException`.
I want to keep it as UnitTest, so using real Context is not possible.

Using Silent runner is an option, but it damages whole file I believe.

How do you handle this issue in your codebase?